# How to reinstall User Quicktime codecs on BigSur MacOS 11.2.3? Playback of screencapture files corrupted

Tags: macos, macos-big-sur

Since updating to latest version 11.2.3 I noticed that if I do a screen capture recording it produces a file which CAN be played back on a different Mac without a problem, but plays back garbage if played using Preview/QuicktimePlayer on the MacMini running MacOS 11.2.3 where it was created.
The picture is mangled, blue and pixels, while showing the original recording for snippets of like 1 or 2s.

The files play fine when moved to a Catalina machine. Also the M1 that has the problem plays back files created on a different machine. When creating a new User and doing a screen capture it records fine!

Apple Support told me that one needs to reinstall the user codecs somehow. They didn't know how exactly it was done but admitted that that was the way one sometimes solves this problem.

How could they have become corrupted in the first place I don't know.

Has someone else experienced this before? How do I fix this without reinstalling the OS or creating a new user. This is surely a problem with BigSur on M1 and is a bug.

I have filed a bug report on the feedback Assistant and the apple developer forum.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/678395#678395021

[image: mangled screenrecording]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to resolve this, but I failed in someways, mainly in dont have success to install codecs pack in the MAC from the company (security reasons). So I always try two options:

1 - Execute the file with KMPlayer;

or/and

2 - Repair the file with some .mov recovery file tool (online or not).

This is a bug, horrible bug, mas I am solving in this two ways above.